# rails ODBC data source problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-services, odbc

Here's an odd situation, if I open a command prompt and start the mongrel server then everything works swimmingly. ActiveRecord talks nicely to the MSSQL server using ODBC if I have a User-DSN defined. But if remove the User-DSN and set just an identical System-DSN then odbc bombs:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default
>   driver specified

I am running Rails on Windows 2003 Server 64bit, using DBI 0.4.1, DBD-ODBC 0.2.4, Rails 2.3.4. I've tried using ODBC manager for 32bit and double-checked that the connection is working from the ODBC Administration panel. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustrating! As it turns out, I had to use regedit to access HKLM/Software/ODBC/ODBC.INI children key (DSN) and changed the SQLServer driver there to be c:\windows\system32\SQLSRV32.dll. Even though the ODBC Administration Panel had this specified and its tests ran fine, it wasn't working until I tweaked the registry. So odd..

Hope it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was entering the ODBC connections into the 64 bit version of the ODBC Data Source Administrator.  When I went to

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

, and re-entered the drivers here (the others were not there!), and all worked fine after that.

[blog entry where I found this](http://coreygilmore.com/blog/2010/04/14/odbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified/)